# can I rely 100% on logical processing to know which objects (columns aliases, tables, etc) I have "available" in subsequent query clauses?

Tags: sql-server

The documentation says that logical processing is used to know what *I have available for the next clauses of a query*, but later **it contradicts itself** by saying that the order can change, that confuses me.

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement)[here]

> Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement
>
> The following steps show the logical processing order, or binding
> order, for a SELECT statement. This order determines when the objects
> defined in one step are made available to the clauses in subsequent
> steps. For example, if the query processor can bind to (access) the
> tables or views defined in the FROM clause, these objects and their
> columns are made available to all subsequent steps. Conversely,
> because the SELECT clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived
> columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding
> clauses. However, they can be referenced by subsequent clauses such as
> the ORDER BY clause. **The actual physical execution of the statement is
> determined by the query processor and the order may vary from this
> list.**
>
> ```
> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. JOIN
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT
> 10. ORDER BY
> 11. TOP
> ```
>
> Warning
>
> The preceding sequence is usually true. **However, there are uncommon
> cases where the sequence may differ.**
>
> For example, suppose you have a clustered index on a view, and the
> view excludes some table rows, and the view's SELECT column list uses
> a CONVERT that changes a data type from varchar to integer. In this
> situation, the CONVERT may execute before the WHERE clause executes.
> Uncommon indeed. Often there is a way to modify your view to avoid the
> different sequence, if it matters in your case.

1. Does this mean that, for example, there will be times when the `WHERE` clause is executed before the `FROM` clause and times when the `FROM` clause is executed first and then the `WHERE` clause?
2. Can I rely 100% on *logical processing* to know which objects (columns aliases, tables, etc) I have "available" in subsequent query clauses?

I also read this from a StackOverflow expert on SQL:

> SQL, by the way, is a descriptive language not a procedural language.
> **A query does not specify the "order of execution". That is determined
> by the compiler and optimizer.** What you are referring to is the "order
> of parsing", which explains how identifiers are resolved in the query.

3. So, what is the point of *logical processing* if *physical processing* (the database, optimizer, indexes, etc at the end of the day) decides the order of execution in a query?
4. Does this mean that *physical processing* can "skip" (alter, modify, I don't know what the right word is) the *logical processing* steps?
5. Does the *logical processing* is executed **first** and then the *physical processing*?, or how?

Comment: The logical processing and physical processing are two quite unrelated things, which may be why you're confused. Will try to explain in an answer if I get a chance.

Comment: Hi @J.D. , I will wait your answer with more details :)

Comment: Cross-post on [so] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77481764/can-i-rely-100-on-logical-processing-to-know-which-objects-columns-aliases-ta

Answer (score 1):

Logical processing is something you understand so you as a human can understand what you are asking the database to do when you write a SQL statement.  There is functionally no code in the database that implements any sort of logical processing (I suppose you could argue that the part of the optimizer that parses the SQL statement and handles scope resolution implements some bits of logical processing if you squint at it just right).

The database optimizer implements physical processing of the statement.  And physical processing can (and does) happen in whatever order the optimizer decides is likely to be most efficient.  That may be to evaluate part of the `where` clause first, then evaluate one of the join conditions, then evaluate more of the `where` clause, then evaluate a function in the `select` list, then filter out more results with another piece of the `where` clause.  There is no requirement (indeed it would be rather unusual) that one part of the statement gets fully evaluated at one point-- it is quite common that the actual query plan shows that steps are interleaved.  And the optimizer is constantly getting updated information in the form of new statistics so it may choose to physically process the same SQL statement in completely different ways from one execution to the next.

If you are trying to figure out what results you are asking the database to return, look at how the statement is logically processed.  If you are trying to tune the performance of a query once you are sure that it is returning the result you want, look at the query plan to see how the optimizer is actually processing it.

Comment: hi @Justin Cave - Can we say that the SELECT, FROM, etc clauses (logical processing) are the "interface" for the sql programmer and the physical processing are the "implementation details", the "how" these clauses are executed, something like encapsulation in object oriented programming?

Comment: @jwa - Logical processing is the "what" and physical processing is the "how".  You could draw some parallels with encapsulation in OOP but it isn't a precise analogy

Comment: So, what exactly do you mean by the "what" and the "how"? I hear that a lot in this context @Justin Cave

Comment: @jwa - Logical processing tells you what the query will return.  It lets you understand what question you are asking the database to answer.  Physical processing tells you how the database will return that result.  That's what you look at if you want to know why the query you wrote is taking so long to return the result.

Comment: Can **I rely 100%** on logical processing to know which objects (columns aliases, tables, etc) I have "available" in subsequent query clauses? @Justin Cave

Comment: @jwa - I'd say no but the question is underspecified.  You can nest subqueries quite deeply within a single part of the statement.  You can only reference aliases 1 or 2 layers of nesting away from where you are.  So I'd tend to argue that logical processing doesn't account for the full scope of aliasing rules.  Someone else might argue that you could come up with a logical processing diagram for the `from` clause alone that would encapsulate those rules.

Comment: @JustinCave Not sure what you mean by "You can only reference aliases 1 or 2 layers of nesting away" you can't reference *any* alias unless it's in your scope or the scope above/outside you, with no limit (where a `JOIN`ed table counts as a completely separate scope, not above or below). Logical processing does encompass the scoping rules, please give an example where it doesn't.

Comment: @Charlieface - As in if I have `from (select a.col1 from a where a.col2 in (select b.col2 from b where b.col3 in (select c.col3 from c where c.col4 in (select d.col4 from d where d.col5 = a.col5))))` I generally can't reference `a.col5` at that level of nesting.  Of course, different databases and different versions will be likely to alter the exact nature of the scoping rules

Comment: No SQL clearly defines what happens there. You can indeed reference any outer reference from an inner subquery. So that would work as you can see https://dbfiddle.uk/5OO8mqSd. Where it doesn't work is when you enclose a whole query in a derived table (eg the `from ()` ) and then try access inner references from outside it or vice versa, or from other joins. You can't do this because a derived table is a separated scope. Also `APPLY` acts like a subquery in this respect, not like a join. But the scoping rules are all clearly defined, there is no ambiguity.